# How to transfer a file from Android to Pc?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm working with BluetoothSockets, for now I'm able to send datas from an Android device to another.

I have to send a file from my device to a PC (windows), which have a Bluetooth Driver. It mean I'm not responsible for the server-side bluetooth implementation, I can't add an custom bluetooth java server inside.

I know we can use the ShareIntent to send datas like

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(picURI);

sharingIntent.setType("image/*");
sharingIntent.setPackage("com.android.bluetooth");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share image"));
```

But I want to use it with an exact Bluetooth Mac adress like "FD:FD:E3:DE:67:00", so with a BluetoothSocket

how can this be acheived ?